# Reading pygame display's current flags (FULLSCREEN etc.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, display

Is it possible to read the current flags that the display has been given? So when one calls `pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, FLAGS)`, I'd love to read them afterwards.

For example I'd like to have an `is_fullscreen()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`pygame.Surface.get_flags`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_flags) method.

> Returns a set of current Surface features. Each feature is a bit in the flags bitmask.

[`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) returns a pygame.Surface. So call the get_flags method of your display and bitwise AND it with the specific flag.

```
def is_fullscreen(display):
    return bool(display.get_flags() & pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I've only been looking at `pygame.display` module this whole time, I feel so silly now.